# Postfix: all external mail loops back to myself

Tags: iptables, postfix, smtp, nat

My problem is that I can't send emails to any external domain using Postfix 3.4.13. However, **I can receive emails sent from external domains**, such as gmail or hotmail. My scenario is a little unconventional, so I'll try my best to explain it:

I host my own personal mail server using some docker containers, and I switched to another ISP and now I am behind a double NAT, so I cannot forward ports. To overcome this I set up a VPN using a low-tier VPS I own at Digital Ocean, and I use this VPS to do forwarding (among other things). So far, I succeeded forwarding ports for SSH and web services, so, unless the MX record (which points to my VPS's public address) is messing things up, I don't find any logical explanation why I can't send emails to external domains, since **this very configuration worked before and works if I'm not behind a machine that does DNAT (to forward SMTP ports)**. You can take a look at my configuration files [here](https://github.com/joseantmazonsb/docker-mail), as well as test it by yourselves using docker.

Postfix's log says:

```
Jan  1 23:38:33 my-server postfix/smtp[214]: warning: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.140.27]:25 greeted me with my own hostname smtp.example.com
Jan  1 23:38:34 my-server postfix/smtp[214]: warning: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.140.27]:25 replied to HELO/EHLO with my own hostname smtp.example.com
Jan  1 23:38:34 my-server postfix/smtp[214]: E60D2BA0658: to=<x@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.140.27]:25, delay=1.2, delays=0.43/0.01/0.72/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for gmail.com loops back to myself)
...
Jan  1 23:40:51 my-server postfix/smtp[222]: warning: host hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.57.161]:25 greeted me with my own hostname smtp.example.com
Jan  1 23:40:51 my-server postfix/smtp[222]: warning: host hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.57.161]:25 replied to HELO/EHLO with my own hostname smtp.example.com
Jan  1 23:40:51 my-server postfix/smtp[222]: E404DBA0947: to=<x@hotmail.com>, relay=hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.57.161]:25, delay=1.1, delays=0.57/0.01/0.48/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for hotmail.com loops back to myself)
```

Iptables DNAT rules:

```
### SMTP
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.99.97.3:25
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 465 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.99.97.3:465
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.99.97.3:587
### IMAP
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 143 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.99.97.3:143
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.99.97.3:993
```

I am using Postfix along with a MySQL database, so adding my domain to `mydestination` will not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just put the mail server on Digital Ocean, then. We don't support hosting services on residential Internet connections.

Comment: I would gladly do that, but my vps can't handle that many containers

Comment: then rent a vroot or root dedicated hardware, on netcup as example existing vroot server that csn handle my 35 containers without any issues

Comment: So don't use containers.

Comment: Your answers don't really fit the question: I would simply like to know why is forwarding ports affecting to SMTP when sending emails because it does not happen when receiving or simply forwarding other services. I ended up using another machine, but I still don't know why is Postfix failing in this particular situation.